# XML: Getting a XML element directly

Tags: java, xml

ich have read tons of articles about reading a XML but nearly all are reading the full document und print it out.

but i would like to get a specific content..

```
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
    <title lang="es">Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</title>
    <author>J. K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

here as an example read out for category= children the content of author = J.K:Rowling.

is that possible and yes has somebody some code for?

thanks

Comment: Please revise your post to correct the language mistakes and also try to be a bit more clear with your problem description - otherwise it is difficult for people to understand.

Comment: Read up on XPath. It's used for querying XML documents.

Comment: thank you. i will have a look for...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, with XPath, you can easily retrieve the value author for category='children'.

Not tested solution but you have the idea (I have prefixed some packages to guide you as some simple classnames in XPATH exist in other packages to address other needs):

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(yourXmlFile);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    org.w3c.dom.Node authorNode= (Node) xpath.evaluate("//book[@category='children']/author", document,
        XPathConstants.NODE);
    String author= authorNode.getTextContent();
```